# I/O Error: Connection reset Pentaho Kettle Error

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm loading manipulating data in sql server with the help of Pentaho kettle 5.4. when i'm trying to load large data i'm getting the below error

**I/O Error: Connection reset**

Comment: give some more details.
so are you able to load some records and then you are getting error or at the time of execution only you are getting error?

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by large data?
how many lines / columns ?

Sometimes what causes the problem is that the query lasts too long.
Then you can add a blocking step to accelerate the output of the data and make it wait until the following steps are ready to "eat" the lines